# How to clean a nested python dict from keys with empty strings and Nones BUT NOT 0 or false

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two issues:

1. I created a function that cleans None keys from my dictionary but I couldn't figure out how to clean recursively if i have dictionaries within my dictionary.
2. I was also able to remove None and empty strings with `if value:` condition I ended up removing false and 0 values which is not what I am looking for. I am only looking to remove keys with None values or empty keys.

   def clean_dict(dict_with_nones):
   return {key: value for key, value in dict_with_nones.items() if value is not None}

This works well in cleaning Nones with a flat dictionary, I tried to add another condition to remove the empty strings:

```
def clean_dict(dict_with_nones):
    return {key: value for key, value in dict_with_nones.items() if value is not None or value != ""}
```

Something about the way I constructed the condition here causes is the None detection not to work as well... I tried surrounding the condition with () but it didnt help.

So back to my question, How can I remove keys with empty values or None values from a nested dictionary?

Comment: your function cleans None in values, not keys. Which one do you want?

Comment: i prefer check values which also are as  a key in your nested dict

Comment: If `value` is `None` it is not `""`; if it is `""` it is not `None`.

Comment: You want "and" not "or".

Comment: Is [this](https://tio.run/##bVHLboMwELzzFSufsIQqEdKHkPoL/YEoB4KXZgU1yDZIUcS3U7AdQxt82p2ZnRnJ3c1cW5l9dGqaBFZQNljIWLe9KpHnEcyPKiBNUptCluipBASVxguWp9D0SsK9zr3FwKFqFdQJDEAS3NkLGfzRMV88ayikgGG0FtjspzSkd1JOLoJcBK3@Z2@m8enGCQIaCfiEu11ZwXI/2vXyZ7VQjbd0RtlQND2mLHliDwu7g2fhKmOBHFcdK4PguDlnYoa/Wun6ej3DGTwFTZpAmA@b@V/1KgS8so3Kct@29drLTmefdg2Hb74ZC8j7A6FHzzHqFEkTu58RnE/TLw) what you want?

Comment: No, I am looking to only remove keys with empty values or None. When I say remove, I mean remove them from the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really want to clean the **keys**, not values:

```
def clean_dict(dict_with_nones):
    if not isinstance(dict_with_nones, dict):
        return dict_with_nones
    return {key: clean_dict(value) for key, value in dict_with_nones.items()
            if key is not None}


test = {None: {'a': 1}, 'b': {'c': {None: 2}, 'd': 3, None: 4}}

out = clean_dict(test)
```

output:

```
{'b': {'c': {}, 'd': 3}}
```

##### variant to avoid yielding null values:

```
def clean_dict(dict_with_nones):
    if not isinstance(dict_with_nones, dict):
        return dict_with_nones
    return {key: v
            for key, value in dict_with_nones.items()
            if key is not None and (v:=clean_dict(value))}

out = clean_dict(test)
```

output:

```
{'b': {'d': 3}}
```

#### removing VALUES

If you meant to remove falsy **values** (None, empty string, etc.)

```
def clean_dict_value(d):
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        return d if d else False # use a custom test if needed
    return {key: v
            for key, value in d.items()
            if (v:=clean_dict_value(value))}


test = {'a': {'b': 1}, 'c': {'d': None, 'e': 3, 'f': {'g': ''}}, 'h': None}

clean_dict_value(test)
```

output:

```
{'a': {'b': 1}, 'c': {'e': 3}}
```

##### removing only `''`, `None` and empty dictionary:

*NB. remove `{}` from `('', None, {})` to keep empty dictionaries*

```
def clean_dict_value(d):
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        return d
    return {key: v
            for key, value in d.items()
            if (v:=clean_dict_value(value)) not in ('', None, {})}


test = {'a': {'b': 1}, 'c': {'d': None, 'e': False, 'f': {'g': ''}}, 'h': None}

clean_dict_value(test)
```

output:

```
{'a': {'b': 1}, 'c': {'e': False}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers - The above solution will also drop 0 and boolean false values. I am interested in dropping only empty strings and Nones.

Comment: @PloniStacker it's simple enough to change the condition, see update